# How does build-order naming work for Zerg?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg, sc2-build-order

For example, does "13-pool" mean "spawn 13 drones, and turn the 13th into a pool" (so that now you are at 12 supply)? Or does it mean "spawn 13 drones, then turn the 14th into a pool" (so that now you are at 13 supply)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means the former.  You build the spawning pool while you're at 13 supply.  Going down to 12 supply is a side-effect but replacing the drone as soon as possible is important to any build.

Answer (score 0):

A 13 pool build means you build the pool at exactly 13 supply.  A 13 pool starts at 6 supply, so you should build 4 drones, an overlord and then 3 more drones before you drop your pool.

Comment: Just being pedantic here, but many players prefer to spawn the overlord at 9 supply, rather than 10. There's some math that goes into it, but the difference is slight, so it shouldn't matter too much.